# How to exclude a directory from WordPress permalinks in a Multisite environment?

Tags: multisite, redirect, htaccess, rewrite-rules, exclude

The scenario is as follows:
A multisite install with three sites:

- `site1.com` (admin)
- `site2.com`
- `site3.com`

**Q:** How to exclude a folder located in the root directory, which should also be associated with `site3.com`?

That is: exclude a particular directory that does not belong to WordPress so that it is accessible from: `site3.com/folderToExclude/`

Back in the day `site3.com` was a stand-alone site (now is part of the mentioned MU install), and this rule used to work:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(folderToExclude/.*)$
```

but that's no longer the case.

This is what the file looks like:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(folderToExclude/.*)$

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) WordPress_04/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ WordPress_04/$1 [L]

RewriteRule . index.php [L]

</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: "site3.com _was_ a stand-alone site" - what is it now? You shouldn't have to do anything to exclude a physical directory, as this should be excluded by default by the standard WP directives in `.htaccess`. So, I'm wondering why you even _needed_ the directive as posted "back in the day"? (That should only have been an optimisation at best.) Please include the contents of your `.htaccess` file - maybe there is something else going on?

Comment: Thanks MrWhite. I was under the impression that a rule on the `.htaccess` file was a must in order to exclude a folder from a WordPress install. I've updated the post to include the current content of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This "exception" would only be required if you are requesting *virtual* URLs within `/folderToExclude`, as opposed to physical files. Any requests to physical directories and files are naturally excluded by the standard WordPress directives.

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(folderToExclude/.*)$
>
> # add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
> RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]
> ```

This *condition* (`RewriteCond` directive) won't do anything where you've put it. `RewriteCond` directives don't do anything by themselves, they apply to the first `RewriteRule` directive that follows. In this case, the above rule is checking that the request URL-path matches `/wp-admin` and does not start `/foldertoExclude/` - the condition is always successful (if A=B then A!=C), so is not doing anything.

However, as written, you couldn't place that condition on the later rule either since the logic is reversed. (Maybe you've used this in the past on a single-site WordPress install?)

Remove that `RewriteCond` directive entirely.

Rather than modifying the WordPress code block you should create an additional rule *before* the `# BEGIN WordPress` section, to exclude all requests that start `/folderToExclude` from being processed at all by the WordPress directives.

For example:

```
# Exclude specific directories
RewriteRule ^folderToExclude($|/) - [L]

# BEGIN WordPress
:
```

No need to repeat the `RewriteEngine` directive. No other `RewriteCond` directives are necessary.

An alternative is to create another `.htaccess` file in the `/folderToExclude` directive with a single `RewriteEngine Off` (or `On`) directive. This will then override the WordPress mod_rewrite directives in the parent `.htaccess` file.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond with such precision and detail, MrWhite. I've marked accepted your answer. Not only solved my doubts but also taught me a lot. Thanks!